# How to find out the columns to be grouped when a query is generated dynamically?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I need to implement a feature where the user will be generating reports dynamically. 
In that feature, the user will be presented with an interface to select some specific modules. Each module will point to a set of tables internally.

Consider the following tables,

```
**Table Name : module_location**
location_id
location_name ->Contains a location name

**Table Name : module_streets**
street_id
street_location_id (F.K module_location.location_id)
street_name ->Contains street name in a location
```

If the user selects the module name `Location`, he is indeed choosing the list tables to be queried on(which is done internally)
In this case, `module_location` and `module_streets` (They will be joined by location id).
After selecting the `Location` module the user has to choose the set of fields which needs to be shown in the dynamic report, once  generated. 
So he'll be provided with an interface to select those fields. The names given in the interface will be alias names for the respective fields in the tables
ie,

The user will be presented with option to select the following

```
Location Name -> Corresponds to the field 'location_name'
Street Name -> Corresponds to the field 'street_name'
```

After selecting the required fields to be shown, the user will have to select some conditions like(count,sum etc)
Suppose, the condition is like `Get the number of streets in a location`, the user will have to add condition `count` against the option `Street Name`.

After selecting the conditions, the user have to simply click the submit button in-order to generate the report.

The issue I'm facing here is how to decide the columns to be grouped. If this is done manually, I know that I need to group the `location_id` to get the count. So how can I do that, if the query is generated dynamically?

Kindly help. The database I'm using is postgresql8.4

Comment: When the user selects to query data for *locations* f.ex., you could always use `GROUP BY module_location.*` (or with less archaic PostgreSQL version, you could use `GROUP BY module_location.location_id` because of the *functional dependency*). That would work with or without any aggregated data.

Comment: But after reading your question twice, to return non-aggregated street names too, you would also have to use a join to an aggregated sub-select. Query builders can help you a lot.